# Live Tile with different sizes

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, live-tile

How can I add different tile sizes to my live tile in windows 8.1 application?

Now I add my live tile for the size 150x310 px like this:

```
var updater = TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication();
updater.EnableNotificationQueue( true );
updater.Clear();

XmlDocument tileXml_310 = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileWide310x150Text07);
tileXml_310.GetElementsByTagName(textElementName)[0].InnerText = "test";

updater.Update(new TileNotification(tileXml_310))
```

if I add another TileTemplate for example with size 150x150 px the live tile not works. it needs very long to change the live tile. with just one template it works fine.
Can anyone tell me a tutorial or an idea to solve the problem with different live tile sizes?

Edit:

How can I do this in a loop?

```
foreach (var info in data)
        {
            XmlDocument tileXml_310 = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileWide310x150Text07);
            XmlNodeList text_tileXml_310 = tileXml_310.GetElementsByTagName("text");
            text_tileXml_310[0].InnerText = "test";

            XmlDocument tileXml_150 = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileSquare150x150Text01);
            XmlNodeList text_tileXml_150 = tileXml_150.GetElementsByTagName("text");
            text_tileXml_150[0].InnerText = "test";          

            IXmlNode newNode = tileXml_310.ImportNode(tileXml_150.GetElementsByTagName("binding").Item(0), true);
            tileXml_310.GetElementsByTagName("visual").Item(0).AppendChild(newNode);

            XmlDocument tileXml_310310 = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileSquare310x310Text05);
            XmlNodeList text_tileXml_310310 = tileXml_310310.GetElementsByTagName("text");
            text_tileXml_310310[0].InnerText = "test";

            IXmlNode newNode2 = tileXml_310.ImportNode(tileXml_310310.GetElementsByTagName("binding").Item(0), true);
            tileXml_310.GetElementsByTagName("visual").Item(0).AppendChild(newNode);
        }
```

Comment: this should help you http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2012/11/09/31-days-of-windows-8-day-9-live-tiles

Comment: @KarthikGanesan ok i understand. how can i do this if i update my tile in a loop like this: edit first post, please post your answer so I can accept it

Comment: What do you actually want to accomplish in your loop? I don't see any fields being populated.